# MVC 4 Images With Spaces In Name Not Displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, razor

I have an MVC 4 site that has a lot of images with spaces in them which cannot be easily changed.  The problem is the site is not displaying any of the images that have spaces, probably because the space is getting translated to a %20. I have tried setting the invalidCharacters attribute of httpruntime in the web.config file to exclude the % with no luck.  Does anyone know of a good way to fix this issue, or what might be causing it?  I have worked in other MVC sites and never had this issue before.  Thanks in advance!

My image tags / paths look like this:

```
<img src="@Model.Picture.Location?width=230&height=285&bgcolor=222425" alt="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GameName)"/>
```

where Model.Picture.Location is the location of the picture on the web server.

Comment: Can we see the generated `<img>` tag? Are you quoting the `src=` attribute?

Comment: how you supply image source path ..

Comment: I edited the post to show an example of how I put in the src attribute and how I do my <img> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was replacing the url in my Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax.cs and was not correctly handling %20.  I used the following code to resolve the issue with my Application_BeginRequest method.

```
     protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        path = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(path);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
           HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(path);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try:

```
 <img src="@(Html.Raw(Model.Picture.Location))?width=230&height=285&bgcolor=222425" alt="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GameName)"/>
```

`Html.Raw()` ensures your string is not encoded.

Comment: No luck with that its still giving a 404.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /BoxArt/GTA%20V.jpg